# combine two selectbox values in r shiny

Tags: r, select, shiny, concatenation, selectinput

I need to combine two select box values in R shiny.
Select box 1 have year, select box 2 have month.

If user select 2018 and 06, I should get 2018-06 into a variable.

I tried `paste(input$year,input$month,sep="-")` But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do, note that I changed from `reative` to `reactiveValues` as I think this should be more intutive for you where you can use the `v$value` which will contain what you want. I suggest you have a read over https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html so you have a better grasp of what is happening

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("value"),
  selectInput("year","year",choices = c(2017,2018),selected = 1),
  selectInput("month","month",choices = c(1:12),selected = 1)

)

server <- function( session,input, output) {

  v <- reactiveValues(value=NULL)

  observe({
    year <- input$year
    month <- input$month
    if(nchar(month)==1){
      month <- paste0("0",month)
    }
    v$value <- paste(year,month,sep="-")
  })

  output$value <- renderText({
    v$value
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: How to get this value into some variable?

Comment: that value is in the variable called `Combined()`

Comment: `Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Comment: If you have a look at the ?reactive you can see that its an expression and not to be used as a value, instead you can either use `reactiveVal` or `reactivevalues`

Comment: I am still getting the same error and my shiny app is closing

Comment: `Error in v$value : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` now this error is coming

Comment: My example works fine, since you dont post the entire app with code I wont speculate on your problem